# Find lower and upper bound of $f: \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_{1}^2 + 2x_{2}^2 + 3x_3^2 \le 6 \} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f$ is given by the formula : $f(x) = 2x_1 + 4x_2 - 6x_3$

Since the domain of $f$ is a bounded and closed set, $f(x)$ does have upper and lower bounds, either in the interior of its domain or on the "edge". If those bounds were in the interior, then there must exist a point $a$ such that $\nabla f(a) = 0 $. However, $\nabla f(x) = [2, 4, -6]$.

This means that both bounds are on the edge $= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_{1}^2 + 2x_{2}^2 + 3x_3^2 = 6 \}$. How can i find those?

Comment: You can either use Lagrange multipliers if you know them... or try to parameterize $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_{1}^2 + 2x_{2}^2 + 3x_3^2 = 6 \}$ taking advantage of spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Lagrange's multipliers: det(i,j,k;2,4.-6;2x,4y,6z)=0-->y=x=-z. Using the constraint as an equation =6 we get x=1=y,z=-1 f=-4=max. Or x=-1=y,z=1 we get f=-12 min